# cron automatically activated after some time

Tags: cron, anacron

I am working on Ubuntu remote server. I deleted automatic cron jobs from my server, but it recovered automatically after some days and occupy my 50% CPU. I attached cron job file from my server here (this is created by some one). Please guide me in this regards.

```
###########
0 0 */3 * * /tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/a/upd>/dev/null 2>&1
5 8 * * 0 /tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/b/sync>/dev/null 2>&1
@reboot /tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/b/sync>/dev/null 2>&1
0 0 */3 * * /tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/aptitude>/dev/null 2>&1
#############################################################
```

Comment: I googled "rsync aptitude" to see if rsync self-installed a server start, and my top hit was a Ubuntu forum thread on crypto-mining malware in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yep, this looks like the same hack as in [Unauthorized access to cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542333/unauthorized-access-to-cron).

Answer (score 0):

The security paper on Medium [We finally learn what hacker Rosey wants](https://medium.com/@j_o_n__w/the-surprisingly-sad-adventures-of-honeypot-cs30-episode-3-dcb1846f3d4e) explain how the crypto-miner malware work, the root cause is a weak root password. see [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) on ServerFault.

Related:

AskUbuntu: [crond64/tsm virus in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115770/crond64-tsm-virus-in-ubuntu)

U&L: [Suspicious crontab entry running 'xribfa4' every 15 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544811/suspicious-crontab-entry-running-xribfa4-every-15-minutes)